# Allow common users to edit their profile (email, image, etc)

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, administration

I'm using Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.0.2 CE and I can't set up users (role = User) to change their personal information. Whenever they click in their names (at the top right of screen) they are redirected to home page.

I have these properties in my portal-ext file

admin.default.role.names=User 
layout.user.private.layouts.enabled=false
layout.user.public.layouts.enabled=false

I tried Roles -> User Role -> Define Permissions --> My account (set all)
But nothing happened.

Any ideas?

Comment: User role is for all the users who have successfully logged-in. So it is already implicitly assigned, so there is no need to do that explicitly. Though by assigning permissions from control panel should work. Try assigning to a different custom role like may be Power user.

Comment: @PrakashK what I did (after a lot of wasted time) was to reset the database from a portal-minimal.sql, and now it's working fine. Anyway, I don't know what was the problem .. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was the problem. I restored the database and it's working fine.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by giving permission to "Power user" role (Roles -> User Role -> Define Permissions --> My account --> Access in My account).